# AngularJS 1.5 returning 404 while Express routing is functioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can view my db data by going to "/api/users".
However, when trying to get the data with AngularJS 1.5 I get a 404.

I think the issue is that the Angular routing is attempting to get to that actual url when it doesn't exist.  But I'm fairly certain my express routing is returning the data on any sort of GET with that url.  I'm really new to AngularJS so forgive me.

Here's my Angular

```
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
    app.controller('HomeController', function($http){
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = "Users";
        vm.users = [];
        vm.getUsers = function(){
            $http.get('../api/users').then(function(response){
                vm.users = response.data;
            },
            function myError(response) {
                vm.title = response.statusText;
            });
        };
        vm.getUsers();

        return true;
    });
    app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: './home.html'
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise('/');
    });
```

Here's the server.js

```
var Model = require('./models/models.js');
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan'); 
var app = express();
var db = "mongodb://localhost/mean_stack";

mongoose.connect(db, function(err, response){
    if(err){
        console.log('Failed to connect to ' + db);
    }else{
        console.log('Successfully connected to ' + db);
    }
});

var router = express.Router();


router.get('/apis/users', function(request, response){
    Model.find({}, function(err, users){
        if(err){
            response.status(404).send(err);
        }else{
            response.status(200).send(users);
        }
    });
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use('/', router);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

I'm probably missing something really basic here, I just can't seem to figure it out.  I also tested it against the tutorial code I'm working with and the instructor's code is working great.
Is the order of my server.js wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `../` relative path on the Angular `$http.get()`. It shouldn't be a relative path.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('HomeController', function($http) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "Users";
    vm.users = [];
    vm.getUsers = function() {
        $http.get('api/users').then(function(response) {
                vm.users = response.data;
            },
            function myError(response) {
                vm.title = response.statusText;
            });
    };
    vm.getUsers();

    return true;
});
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: './home.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Also on the Express side, I noticed that you get route may have a misspelling. An 's' added to 'api' by accident?

```
router.get('/api/users', function(request, response){
    Model.find({}, function(err, users){
        if(err){
            response.status(404).send(err);
        }else{
            response.status(200).send(users);
        }
    });
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Wow.  Spelling.  That did it.  Thank you.  A follow-up am I correct in saying that Angular routing is really AJAX or promises and they simple change url hashes??  Is that close or am I missing something?  Thank you.

Comment: Effectively your $http get/post/etc should match up with the path's specified in your Express resource routes. The $routeProvider routes on the Angular side is performing hash navigation, HTML template loading, controller initialization, etc. While $http is explicitly called to perform ajax calls. Routing in Angular is separate from the $http/ajax calls. I'd continue having 'api' or some identifier in your Express routes to differentiate Express routes from Angular routes.